# Websphere Application Server 7 Datasource test connection error

Tags: websphere, datasource

I am trying to connect data source with correct username and password in Websphere application server 7. I am getting following error:

```
[10/17/16 12:34:18:510 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati W   DSRA8200W: DataSource Configuration: DSRA8020E: Warning: The property 'metaDataSource' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource.
[10/17/16 12:34:18:635 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati W   DSRA8200W: DataSource Configuration: DSRA8020E: Warning: The property 'translateBoolean' does not exist on the DataSource class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource.
[10/17/16 12:34:18:932 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati I   DSRA8203I: Database product name : DB2 UDB for AS/400
[10/17/16 12:34:18:948 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati I   DSRA8204I: Database product version : 07.01.0000 V7R1m0
[10/17/16 12:34:18:948 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati I   DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name  : AS/400 Toolbox for Java JDBC Driver
[10/17/16 12:34:18:948 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati I   DSRA8206I: JDBC driver version  : 7.0
[10/17/16 12:34:19:010 EDT] 000411a4 access        E   Mon Oct 17 12:34:18 EDT 2016  run(): Caught IOException:
                                 java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.DataStream.readFromStream(DataStream.java:48)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.ClientAccessDataStream.construct(ClientAccessDataStream.java:46)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ThreadedServer.run(AS400ThreadedServer.java:321)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

[10/17/16 12:34:19:104 EDT] 00041199 DSConfigurati I   DSRA8030I: Successfully connected to DataSource, with 2 warnings.
```

Can anyone tell why it is coming like this. Because I have searched lot of times in internet there is no exact match of answers for this error.

Comment: Your connection seems to be fine. Please check if your DB user has the appropriate permissions to explore the database.

Comment: Are both your WAS instance and the DB running on IBM i ?

Comment: You can also enable JDBC trace to see more specific information https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21654565 However, as noted by F Rowe it appears your datasource has some properties set that do not apply to that datasource.